# ArrayList  - передача в другой класс

Tags: java

Добрый день. Подскажите неразумному новичку ответ на следующий вопрос:
В наличии имеем 2 класса: Main, Class1, Class2. В мейне я создаю объекты. В классе1 этот объект добавляется в `ArrayList` с помощью не статического метода. Не могу для себя понять, каким образом я могу заполучить этот эрейлист в класс2?

Заранее спасибо всем кто подскажет

Answer (score 1):

В `Class2` нужно добавить метод

```
pulic void setList(List list){
    this.list = list;
}
```

После чего вызвать его в месте, где нужно в класс2 передать список, и после этого уже можно работать с этим списком в классе2

Comment: Чего то не получается(( Видимо совсем запущеный случай

Comment: @Богдан Михальченко, ну, код в студию!

Comment: Что ж.. Какой вопрос, таков и ответ..